# Duplicates in question list

Tags: bug, questions, ios-app, question-lists

<sup>I've tagged as bug but this may not actually be a bug and may be more a feature request so apologies if I've got that wrong.</sup>

When viewing questions, using the new app, in the question list there are duplicates. The reason for this is activity but for me at least it's a bit confusing and not needed.

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot 3:**

[image]

---

**This is a screenshot of the original app:**

[image]

---

**It gets even more noisy when there are more than one answer:**

[image]

Can it be modified in any way so that it looks like the view in the original app?

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you're seeing between the two apps is that in the Stack Exchange app you've created an "active vb.net" filtered sort and in the Stack Overflow app, you are searching for "vb.net", possibly through a saved search.

To get the same view in the Stack Overflow app, you'll want to do the following steps, or similar:

1. While not in active search, tap the sort header immediately below the search bar. It will probably read "active" or "newest" in lower case.
2. Tap the + icon in the top right of the popup to create a new sort.
3. Tap "Tagged" and search for "vb.net".
4. Tap "Sort" and select "Active".
5. Tap "Save".

[image: Screenshot showing the steps outlined above.]

Similarly, you could do this from a question tagged "vb.net":

1. Open a question tagged "vb.net".
2. Tap the tag "vb.net" under a question's title. This will open a list of the newest questions tagged "vb.net".
3. Tap the sort header below the search bar. It should read "vb.net".
4. Change the sort from "Newest" to "Active".
5. Tap "Save".

Comment: This does highlight that more could be done for discoverability here.  E.g., search to sort conversion button when there's an equivalent tag search.

Comment: That's done it, I hadn't realised I'd done that on the SE app to be honest. I guess I just did it when I first downloaded then when moving to the SO app I just assumed I'd followed the same path. Thanks for this, I'm happy enough with the saved search as it also solved my _having to search every time I loaded the app_ problem which as I've now read has never been a problem, just me being a little lazy.